# ¿Cómo puedo modificar el método de bisección para que me salga mas de una raíz?

Tags: c++

Quiero que en el siguiente código me salga en pantalla más de una raíz, intenté varias cosas pero no consigo hacerlo. Únicamente me da una de las raíces. Intento hacer el teorema de Bolzano automático mientras hace el método de bisección, para que la persona no tenga que escoger un intervalo, solo tenga que poner la función.
Aquí está el código:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cmath>
 #include <iomanip>
 using namespace std;
 double f(double x);

 double f(double x){
 return pow(x,3)+pow(x,2)-(2*x);
 }

 int main(){
double a,b;
float xr;
double tolerancia=0.0001;
int n;

       for(double i=-100;i<=100;i+=0.2){
          cin>>a;
       } for(double i=a+tolerancia;i<=0.2;i+=tolerancia){
          cin>>b;
       }
  do {
         xr = (a + b) / 2.0;

         // Vemos si cumple o no cumple
         if (f(xr)<=tolerancia) { // xr sería la raiz de funcion
         
            cout <<"Para una tolerancia de "<< tolerancia <<" la raiz de f(x), la x= "<<xr<<endl;
            
         }
            if (f(xr) * f(a) > 0) {
               a = xr;
            } else if (f(xr) * f(b) > 0) {
               b = xr;
            }
         
            if(f(a)==0){
        cout<<"Una de las raices es: "<<a;
    }
    if (f(b)==0){
        cout<<"Una de las raices es: "<<b<<endl;}
          break; 
          } while (f(xr) !=0.001);
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que los `break` interrumpen la estructura del código, ya que finalizan el bucle `do while` y luego el programa termina con `return 0;`, ejecutando solo una pequeña parte del código de `main()`.

Aun así no entiendo el propósito de los bucles `for`. Estos no hacen nada, ya que las variables declaradas en su interior se destruyen al finalizar el bucle y te quedas con `a` y `b` que fueron declarados anteriormente, pero al no asignarle valores se produce comportamiento indefinido por acceder a memoria sin inicializar, lo cual es un problema aun más importante.

> intente varias cosas pero no consigo hacerlo

También seria útil saber que intentaste para así llegar a una mejor solución.

> para que la persona no tenga que escoger un intervalo, solo tenga que poner la función.

Por último agregar que no entiendo esto. En el código en ningún momento se ingresan datos (ejemplo: `std::cin`), solo se utiliza la salida (`std::cout`).

---

EDIT: Encontré información acerca del método de bisección y de como implementar el algoritmo en C++. Usé un código existente, lo modifiqué y le añadí comentarios explicando un poco la estructura del programa:

```
/*
    Copyright (c) 2020 Luis Cabrera Benito
    Licenciado bajo la licencia MIT

    El texto de arriba debe ser incluido en cualquier redistribución
*/

/*
    Este código ha sido adaptado y modificado por Javier (https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/296675/javier),
    apegándose a lo establecido en la licencia MIT.
*/ 

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

float f(float x) {
    return pow(x, 3) + pow(x, 2) - (2 * x);
}

int main() {

    // Declaración de todas las variables
    float a = 1;
    float b = 2;
    int iteracion = 0;
    float aprox = 0;
    float ultimo_xr = 0;
    float fa = 0;
    float fb = 0;
    float xr = 0;
    float fxr = 0;
    float fa_fxr = 0;

    // Encabezado de la tabla de valores
    std::cout << "|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << "|  i |       a     |      b      |    f(a)     |    f(b)     |      xr     |    f(xr)    |f(a) * f(xr) |   aprox   |\n";
    std::cout << "|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";

    while (true) {

        // Cuenta las iteraciones del bucle
        iteracion++;

        // Se asignan los valores correspondientes a las variables para la iteración actual
        fa = f(a);
        fb = f(b);
        xr = (a + b) / 2;
        fxr = f(xr);
        fa_fxr = fa * fxr;
        aprox = abs(xr - ultimo_xr);

        // Se imprimen los valores con el formato adecuado para las dimensiones de la tabla
        printf("|%3d |%12.8f |%12.8f |%12.8f |%12.8f |%12.8f |%12.8f |%12.8f |%12.8f\n", iteracion, a, b, fa, fb, xr, fxr, fa_fxr, aprox);

        // Se actualiza el valor de a o b segun corresponda
        if (fa_fxr > 0) a = xr;
        else b = xr;

        // Se guarda el xr actual para su uso en la siguiente iteración
        ultimo_xr = xr;

        // Si la diferencia entre xr y el xr de la iteracion anterior llega a 0, se sale del bucle y se termina el programa
        if (aprox == 0) break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Entonces cuales break bloquean el funcionamiento de mi programa?

Comment: Todos. Cada vez que la ejecución llega a un break, el programa se termina.

Comment: Cuando quito todos los break, el programa se queda ejecutando aun.

Comment: Recuerda lo que te dije acerca del bucle `do while`, `while(1)` es un bucle infinito.

Comment: Tengo poco tiempo con la programación (3 meses) y estoy bastante perdido... Podemos hablar por otro sitio si es posible? Discord por ejemplo?

Comment: Prefiero no dar mi Discord por acá, tampoco sé si esta permitido. Pero aún así puedo buscar más información y páginas que te pueden ayudar a implementar el algoritmo que quieres.

Comment: @XNX Ahí modifiqué la respuesta con un código perfectamente funcional, espero que te sirva.